# How to easily switch between Webrat and Selenium?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, webrat

Please let me know how can I easily switch between Webrat and Selinium? Selinium takes longer as it simulates by opening the real browser.  In some cases I do not need this and just Webrat, showing results in command line is just fine and faster.  Is there anyway to configure cucumber to switch between Webrat and Selenium??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) is designed to be a webrat replacement, and it supports multiple back-end drivers (including Selenium) and you can switch between them, even during a test run. For example, maybe you want most of your tests to run fast but some require ajax testing / cross-browser testing and for those you can switch to Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this. But the easiest is:

Tag individual files/Scenarios with @selenium to invoke selenium and then use @javascript as your default driver which uses webrat as the default driver, if I recall correctly.

This will only call Selenium when you invoke it directly.

Comment: Thanks Tyler, Please let me know specific configurations to be made ?